# How to add an advert pic of your app on android market

Tags: android

Added an image from android market. I would like to know how can we get that image in market.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to "**Edit application**" page of developer console, select tab "**Product details**", look for header "**Upload assets**"(usually it is first), and finally you need option "**Feature Graphic**"

Answer (score 1):

It is one of the optional images that you can upload in the developer portal. Its known as the "feature image". [Here is some more info.](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-market-featured-image.html) To get that on the market just log into the developer portal and upload an image.

Answer (score 0):

i use Paintshop Pro and do a screen capture from my emulator. or i just resize my splash screen and upload it.

Answer (score 0):

Just Create the advertise poster on Photoshop of the mention size of android market and there is one option on android market to upload the application banner on android market through that you can upload the picture to android market website